# Removing Duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, inner-join, having

I need to select all orders that are not yet invoiced
     `and BR.isInvoiced = 0`

`Select DG.DateGenerated, oit.OrderIdentifier, BR.isInvoiced, BR.hash, 
    BR.OrderNumber, UL.FirstName, UL.LastName   from [Order] O
    INNER JOIN BillingReport BR
    ON O.OrderNumber = BR.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN UsersLib UL
    ON UL.UserID = O.UserId
    INNER JOIN Order_Identifier_Transactional OIT
    ON O.OrderNumber = OIT.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN
     (Select OP.OrderNumber, OP.DateGenerated from OrderProducts OP 
     group by OP.OrderNumber, op.DateGenerated
      having op.DateGenerated in (select MAX(op.DateGenerated) from orderproducts ))as DG
    ON DG.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
    where O.Status = 'COMPLETED' 
    and BR.isInvoiced = 0
    and UL.UserName not like '%Support%' 
    and UL.AccountNumber != '10000001001' 
    and BR.invoicepdf is NULL 
    and BR.ispaid = 0`

then select only the most recent dategenerated per ordernumber
but using this query i still find some duplicates like this:

[image]

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that the DateGenerated for those two highlighted records are not the same. Therefore, they are technically different records and NOT duplicates.

Comment: yes. but we're looking for the MOST RECENT DATE GENERATED. as seen on the photo attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest way to fix your problem:

```
SELECT MAX(DateGenerated), OrderIdentifier, isInvoiced, hash, OrderNumber, 
    FirstName, LastName
FROM (Select DG.DateGenerated, oit.OrderIdentifier, BR.isInvoiced, BR.hash, 
    BR.OrderNumber, UL.FirstName, UL.LastName   from [Order] O
    INNER JOIN BillingReport BR
    ON O.OrderNumber = BR.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN UsersLib UL
    ON UL.UserID = O.UserId
    INNER JOIN Order_Identifier_Transactional OIT
    ON O.OrderNumber = OIT.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN
     (Select OP.OrderNumber, OP.DateGenerated from OrderProducts OP 
     group by OP.OrderNumber, op.DateGenerated
      having op.DateGenerated in (select MAX(op.DateGenerated) from orderproducts ))as DG
    ON DG.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
    where O.Status = 'COMPLETED' 
    and BR.isInvoiced = 0
    and UL.UserName not like '%Support%' 
    and UL.AccountNumber != '10000001001' 
    and BR.invoicepdf is NULL 
    and BR.ispaid = 0)
GROUP BY OrderIdentifier, isInvoiced, hash, OrderNumber, FirstName, LastName
```

I took the entire query you had, wrapped it in quotes, then selected from it with a MAX aggregate function wrapped around DateGenerated. At the end, I added the GROUP BY clause for all the other fields.

Comment: Duplicates we're still appeared.

Comment: This code works now, but I put an alias in the end of the parenthesis
    and 
`BR.ispaid = 0) as OA `
and the code works. Thank you for your help and Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

You've got an alias in your MAX select

`(select MAX(op.DateGenerated) from orderproducts )`

Try this instead:

`(select MAX(DateGenerated) from orderproducts where ordernumber = op.ordernumber )`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UNIQUE` on the second `INNER JOIN`?

```
INNER JOIN
     (Select UNIQUE OP.OrderNumber, OP.DateGenerated
      from OrderProducts OP 
      group by OP.OrderNumber, op.DateGenerated
      having op.DateGenerated in
            (select MAX(op.DateGenerated)
             from orderproducts )) as DG
ON DG.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
```

Comment: Duplicates  are also appeared when trying the UNIQUE code

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DG.DateGenerated, oit.OrderIdentifier, BR.isInvoiced, BR.hash, 
    BR.OrderNumber, UL.FirstName, UL.LastName   from [Order] O
    INNER JOIN BillingReport BR
    ON O.OrderNumber = BR.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN UsersLib UL
    ON UL.UserID = O.UserId
    INNER JOIN Order_Identifier_Transactional OIT
    ON O.OrderNumber = OIT.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN
     (Select OP.OrderNumber, OP.DateGenerated from OrderProducts OP 
     group by OP.OrderNumber, op.DateGenerated
      having op.DateGenerated in (select MAX(op.DateGenerated) from orderproducts OP1 WHERE OP.OrderNumber =  OP1.OrderNumber))as DG
    ON DG.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
    where O.Status = 'COMPLETED' 
    and BR.isInvoiced = 0
    and UL.UserName not like '%Support%' 
    and UL.AccountNumber != '10000001001' 
    and BR.invoicepdf is NULL 
    and BR.ispaid = 0
```

You are missing `WHERE OP.OrderNumber =  OP1.OrderNumber` when find MOST RECENT DATE GENERATED. I hope it will help you.